# functionality of facebook like button

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, button, facebook-like

I want facebook like button and its functionality in my web page made in php. I have successfully done that. Now my question is, how the data will be stored into the database(mysql) of registered facebook user who has been clicked the like button.

Comment: Make an ajax call and insert in your database on clicking the like?

Answer (score 1):

You can use call back function like

```
FB.Event.subscribe
```

For example, suppose you want to record Likes in your database whenever a button is clicked:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
function(response) {
    alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
}
```

);

Refer http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/ for details

Comment: +1 for mentioning the event subscribe call. But what is this ); crying smiley doing in the post?

Comment: but how can I get the username of the facebook owner who clicks on that like button? Is there any option?

Comment: for calling the above mentioned function, shall I have to include any other js file? Actually I am new in FB module.

Answer (score 0):

The data will be stored on Facebook servers. Your website doesn't need to care about storing them.